# Reduce SQL statement with sum of col of result

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

```
select *, 
  (a / 100) as a_calc, 
  (select sum(a_calc) from foo where c = ? and d = ?) as a_calc_sum 
from foo 
where c = ? and d = ? 
order by a;
```

The purpose here is I want to return all rows matching the original query (without the sum) and have mysql calculate the sum of a_calc for me instead of issuing a separate query.  Without the subselect it seems I only get the first row in the query with the correct sum attached.

Any ideas how to reduce the above query?

Comment: You want the sum of all matching rows as a column in your result? What do you mean by 'reduce the query' ?

Comment: This is far too abstract to obtain a decent answer. Please provide a sample schema on http://sqlfiddle.com and show in your question the expected result of the query when applied on the test schema.

Comment: By reducing I mean, I would like to simplify the SQL query as much as possible including possibly factoring out the duplicate 'where' clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to avoid running the subquery for every row - here's how:

```
select *, 
  a / 100 as a_calc,
  a_calc_sum
from foo 
join (select sum(a / 100) a_calc_sum from foo where c = ? and d = ?) x
where c = ? and d = ? 
order by a;
```